# Why isnt my jquery changing my div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the top div so when either button is selected, it will change it according to the button that is clicked on.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="bulb" id="bulb1"></div>
    <div class="bulb" id="bulb2"></div>
    <button id="blue">blue</button>
    <button id="yellow">yellow</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // initial load up coverts to this colour
    $('.bulb1').css("background-color","black");    

    //call the colour change functions when clicked
    $('#blue').click("background-color", "setBlue");
    $('#yellow').click("background-color", "setYellow");

});

function setYellow(){

    $('#bulb1').css("background-color","#yellow");

}

function setBlue(){

    $('#bulb1').css("background-color","#blue");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#blue').click(function() {
    $('#bulb1').css({
        'background-color' : 'blue'
    });
});
```

Or

```
$('#blue').click(function() {
    setBlue();
});

function setBlue() {
    $('#bulb1').css({
       'background-color': 'blue'
     });    
}
```

You can refactor your code like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initial load up coverts to this colour
    setColor('black');  

    //call the colour change functions when clicked
    $('#blue').click(function() {
      setColor('blue');
    });

    $('#yellow').click(function() {
      setColor('yellow');
    });

});

function setColor(color) {    
    $('#bulb1').css({
       'background-color': color
     });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting the wrong element initially:

```
$('.bulb1').css("background-color","black");
```

should be

```
$('#bulb1').css("background-color","black");
```

or

```
$('.bulb').css("background-color","black");
```

depending on which element(s) you're trying to select.

Answer (score 1):

Correction and Solution based on your code-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // initial load up coverts to this colour
    $('#bulb1').css("background-color","black");    

    //call the colour change functions when clicked
    $('#blue').click(function(){
        setBlue();
    });

    $('#yellow').click(function(){
        setYellow();
    });
});

function setYellow(){
    $('#bulb1').css("background-color","yellow");
}

function setBlue(){
    $('#bulb1').css("background-color","blue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/663en9nc/1/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // initial load up coverts to this colour
    $('.bulb').css("background-color","black");    

    //call the colour change functions when clicked
    $('#blue').click(function()
    {
        $('#bulb1').css("background-color","blue");
    });
    $('#yellow').click(function()
    {
        $('#bulb1').css("background-color","yellow");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#yellow').click(setYellow);
$('#blue').click(setBlue);
```

or delegate the click command to listen for the 'click' event for your element on your document:

```
$(document).delegate('#yellow', 'click', setYellow);
$(document).delegate('#blue', 'click', setBlue);
```